# Selecting html element by multiple attributes with javascript or prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have several html input elements which all look something like this:

```
<input id="1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="123" name="myinput" />
```

How do I fetch the input element with javascript by multiple attributes? For instance I want to fetch the input element which is of type radio, is checked and have a value that equals 123?

Basically I want to do something like this (I know this doesn't work):

```
var myElement = document.body.select('input[type=radio]:checked', 'input[value=123]');
```

Comment: your id should be unique so using `document.querySelector('#1')` should be enough

Comment: Ok bad example from my part then. My questions remains though...

Comment: Just replace document.body.select with document.querySelectorAll. Also, IDs mustn't begin with a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With prototype this should work:

```
$$("input[type=radio][id=1]:checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that dose that.

```
function getInput() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=1, element=elements[0];element = elements[i++];) {
        if(element.type=="radio" && 
            element.checked==true && 
            element.id=="1") {
            return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Change the if statement inside the loop to your liking.